# In swift, how do I do this?

Tags: swift, numbers, integer

My English is not enough to search the question. So, I have to write here. My integer is 600000000 for ex. I want to convert it like this: 600,000,000. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extension Int {
    struct Number {
        static let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    }
    var addThousandSeparator:String {
        Number.formatter.groupingSeparator = "."
        Number.formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
        return Number.formatter.stringFromNumber(self)!
    }
}

let myInteger = 600000000
let myIntegerString = myInteger.addThousandSeparator  // "600.000.000"
```

Comment: I add this in view controller.swift, but there was an error: declaration is only valid at file scope. How do i fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Just add this extension at the bottom of your view controller (outside your view controller)

Comment: Thanks for everything!

Comment: @BatuhanKök  you are welcome